# How to deal with JS async function in switch case statement

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I met a problem in JS async function.
Here is the sample code:

```
switch (name) {
case "0":
    async_function(1, function() {

    });
    return;
case "1":
    console.log("1");
    return;
}
doSomething();
```

As you can see, if case "0" run, it is probably code will return before async_function.
That is not what I want. Is there any good way to deal with this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get your `async_function`? Is it a placeholder for a `setTimeout`?

Comment: The solution is always the same: If a function performs an async operation, you either have to make it accept a callback or return a promise. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196 for examples.

Comment: In fact, here I use "chrome.storage.sync.get()" API.

Comment: you might want to change the `return` to `break` inside the `switch` if you want to execute `doSomething`. Also what are you trying to do... do you want to execute doSomething after the async function is executed

Comment: a skeleton to the solution could look like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mfp7gqhf/1/